# Get perfect match array using different variables in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have three variables

```
$region ='APJ'; 
$sub_region = 'India';
$country = 'India'
```

and i have multiple arrays like

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
        [region] => APJ
        [subregion] => India
        [country] => 
    )
  [1] => Array
    (
        [region] => APJ
        [subregion] =>china 
        [country] => 
    )
  [2] => Array
    (
        [region] => WW
        [subregion] =>france 
        [country] => France
    )
  [3] => Array
    (
        [region] => EMEA
        [subregion] =>mema 
        [country] => France
    )
)
```

I need to find the perfect match array for using these three variables.

In the above example we have 4 arrays with different values.

First array matching region and sub region level also.

Second array only region level is matching.

All other are not matching even one value also.

So i choose the first array as result.

So using php how i find the perfect matching array in this kind of scenario?

Comment: could you put the php array variable as is.

Comment: like this:- $cars = array(array("region"=>,"subregion","country"),array("BMW",15,13),array("Saab",5,2),array("Land Rover",17,15));

Comment: Show us what you have tried, and include any errors you've has with your attempt.

Comment: @Epodax i tried to find a an array, ie most matching with my input variables. if all the variables is matching any one of the array, then that is perfect match. if not the latest two matches else only one match

Comment: Edit your question to include the code you have tried in order to get the desired functionality.

Comment: @Epodax ok, i will edit

Comment: Please read this, if you did not yet: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Concept: "Ranking"

- **Create a comparison array** with the same structure as the definiton arrays
- **Loop through all definitions** and …

  - **Count matches** (rank) for each definition (loop through comparison array).
  - **Store the mathing level (rank)** in the definition array itself (additional key: *_level*).
- **Keep the index of the highest ranked** definition array.

Result: **The index of the definition array with the highest rank** (*$highestlevel*).
(= The first definition with the highest ranking)

### Code

```
<?php 

$defs = array (                              // Definitions
    array(
        'region' => 'APJ',          // to be compared
        'country' => '',            // to be compared
        'typeofrec' => 1, 
        'TotalAllocations' => 0,
        'TotalTransfersOut' => 0, 
        'subregion' => 'India',     // to be compared
        'TotalTransfersIn' => 0, 
        'StartOfAllocation' => 0, 
        'ApprovedActivities' => 10,
        'AvailableBalance' => -10, 
        'Exposure' => 0, 
    ),
    array(
        'region' => 'APJ',
        'subregion' => 'china ',
        'country' => '',
    ),
    array(
        'region' => 'WW',
        'subregion' => 'france',
        'country' => 'France',
    ),
    array(
        'region' => 'EMEA',
        'subregion' => 'mema',
        'country' => 'France',
    ),
);

// Comparison array
// Instead of ...
//   $region ='APJ'; 
//   $sub_region = 'India';
//   $country = 'India' 

$testarray = array(                          // Comparison array
    'region' => 'APJ',
    'subregion' => 'India',
    'country' => 'India',
);

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
$highestlevel = 0;                           // Index of highest ranked definition
foreach ($defs as $ix => $def) {             // Loop through all definitions
    $defs[$ix]['_level'] = 0;                // Add new entry to array
    foreach($testarray as $key => $value) {  // Loop throug comparison values
                                             // Increment ranking level if matched
        if (trim($def[$key]) == trim($value)) $defs[$ix]['_level']++;
        // Variant "case ignored":
        // if (strtolower(trim($def[$key])) == strtolower(trim($value))) $defs[$ix]['_level']++;
    }
                                             // Keep index of highest ranked
    if (!isset($defs[$highestlevel]['_level']) || $defs[$highestlevel]['_level'] < $defs[$ix]['_level']) $highestlevel = $ix;
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------

                                             // Display the result
echo '<h3>Result</h3><pre>'; var_dump($defs[$highestlevel]); echo '</pre>';
```

Main advantages:

- Flexibility:
  The code only assumes array structures. Neither key names nor element types nor fixed array lengths are assumed. So it Works with different values and array lengths.
- Compactness.

### Result

```
array(12) {
    ["region"]=> string(3) "APJ"
    ["country"]=> string(0) ""
    ["typeofrec"]=> int(1)
    ["TotalAllocations"]=> int(0)
    ["TotalTransfersOut"]=> int(0)
    ["subregion"]=> string(5) "India"
    ["TotalTransfersIn"]=> int(0)
    ["StartOfAllocation"]=> int(0)
    ["ApprovedActivities"]=> int(10)
    ["AvailableBalance"]=> int(-10)
    ["Exposure"]=> int(0)
    ["_level"]=> int(2)
}
```

Comment: thanks for tour effort. But actualy my array contains some other and non comparable values. Example Array
 Array
        (
            [Region] => EMEA
            [SubRegion] => MEMA
            [Country] => Turkey
            [typeofrec] => 1
            [TotalAllocations] => 0
            [TotalTransfersOut] => 0
            [TotalTransfersIn] => 0
            [StartOfAllocation] => 0
            [ApprovedActivities] => 10
            [AvailableBalance] => -10
            [Exposure] => 0
        )  . Both arrays are same key values

Comment: So this cause how i use only those three array indexes

Comment: First of all: the solution covers different keys and different length arrays. The **comparison array** only rules what comparisons are made. So, only the _region_, _subregion_, and _country_ elements are compared if the comparison array contains these only. I'm quite sure it will work with the array you posted above. And the place of the items is irrelevant too, just the key names (and values, of course) of the comparison array are relevant. Just try it.

Comment: And, if you care about the additonal _\_level_ entries: the ranking could equally be held in a separate, "throw away" array.

Comment: I've added your example in my answer ... and successfully tested.

Comment: Thanks, it's working perfectly. is there any way to get the array index of the selected(highly matched ) array?

Comment: Yes, it is already in the variable **$highestlevel**. As you can see in my example I'm using it in the statement _var_dump($defs[$highestlevel]);_ which dumps the contents of exactly this array.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You make me the day very easy. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++)
{

    if(($arr[$i]['region']==$region) &&  ($arr[$i]['subregion']==$sub_region) &&  ($arr[$i]['country']==$country) )
    { 
        echo "3"."index".$i;
    }
    elseif( (($arr[$i]['region']==$region) &&  ($arr[$i]['subregion']==$sub_region)) || ( ($arr[$i]['subregion']==$sub_region) && ($arr[$i]['country']==$country) ) || ( ($arr[$i]['region']==$region) && ($arr[$i]['country']==$country) )  )
    {
        echo "2"."index".$i;
    }
    elseif(($arr[$i]['region']==$region) ||  ($arr[$i]['subregion']==$sub_region) || ($arr[$i]['country']==$country))
    {
       echo "1"."index".$i;
    }
    else
    { 
        echo "not found";
    }
}


$arr is your array.
in above code it first search for perfect match means all case are matche
in second case it match for two
in third case it match for atleast one
3 is the top priority and get the index value
```

Comment: @sahil Manchal this solution don't work. because i need most matching case.

Comment: you says that you need perfect match

Comment: @SahilManchal    if all the variables is matching any one of the array, then that is perfect match. if not the latest two matches else only one match

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
$region ='APJ'; 
$sub_region = 'India';
$country = 'India' 
$ret ="";
foreach($yourarr as $key=> $subArr){
    /* If region,subregion & country values matches given data return mached array value  */
    if($subArr['region'] == $region && $subArr['subregion'] == $sub_region  && $subArr['country'] == $country){
        $matArr = $arr[$key];
        break;
    }
    /* Else If any of the 2 matches with given data return the specific array value  */
    else if(
        ($subArr['region'] == $region && $subArr['subregion']) ||

        ($subArr['subregion'] == $sub_region  && $subArr['country'] == $country ) ||

        ($subArr['region'] == $region && $subArr['country'] == $country )
        ){
        $matArr = $arr[$key];
        break;

    }
    /* Else any of the value matches return the specific array value*/
    else if($subArr['region'] == $region || $subArr['subregion'] == $sub_region  || $subArr['country'] == $country){
        $matArr = $arr[$key];
        break;
    }


}

echo "Matching Array Is:";
print_r($matArr);
```